# datamapper in mule- facing issue to map many to single because the child elements of input are disabled

Tags: xml, mule, datamapper, transformer-model

mule-datamapper:
I am giving an input xml file as input.xml using this i am creating a  schema  and as output i am giving output xml in mule for this also i am creating xsd.

Input xml:

```
<abcd xmlns:ns0="http://a.b.com/d">
<temporaryaddress>

<address id="1">
<name>x</name>
<country>india</country>
<zipcode>890765</xipcode>
</address>


<address id="2">
<name>y</name>
<country>india</country>
<zipcode>890766</xipcode>
</address>
</temporaryaddress>
</abcd>
```

and current output xml is like

```
<abcd xmlns:ns1="http://e.f.com/g">
<temporaryaddress>
<address>
<name>y</name>
<country>india</country>
<zipcode>890766</xipcode>
</address>
</temporaryaddress>
</abcd>
```

when i tried mapping in mule it is showing the elements under temporaryaddress is disabled in input i am unable to map those.

Desired output xml:

```
<abcd>
<temporaryaddress>
<address>
<name>x</name>
<country>india</country>
<zipcode>890765</xipcode>
</address>
</temporaryaddress>

<temporaryaddress>
<address>
<name>y</name>
<country>india</country>
<zipcode>890766</xipcode>
</address>
</temporaryaddress>
</abcd>
```

i need to map many to single and get the output differently with root element.

In crisp: I have two address elements inside temporary address. In the output I need two temporary address elements with 1st address copied into  1st temporary address element and 2nd address of input into 2nd temporary address of output.
Any links/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create the DataMapper output schema from the desired output xml, otherwise it expects only a single temporaryaddress element and fails for not being able to map many-to-one. Another option is to edit the output xsd manually to allow multiple temporaryaddress elements.